# Query Syntax for Solr+Php

Tags: php, solr, lucene

I have been searching around for examples but the documentation on:
http://php.net/manual/en/solrclient.query.php
and
https://www.ayalon.ch/en/code-samples/solr-php-client-example

does not give me enough information to alter for my setup.

I am trying to execute a solr query using php from my website.
The search box form method is post and the input name is q.

This is all of the php I have at the moment; I was testing the connection.

```
<?php
require_once('C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\dist\solr-php-client-master\Apache\Solr\Service.php');

    $client = new Apache_Solr_Service( 'localhost', '8983', '/solr/#/sqltest' );

    if ( ! $client->ping() ) {
    echo 'Solr service not up dude.';
    }
    else{
        echo 'ayee we have a connection here!';
    }
//to view the specifics of this setup use
//var_dump($client);

?>
```

Being new to php, Im really trying to find the proper way to perform the search and display the default json response.
I already have documents indexed to search so my code does not need to add any docs as seen in some of the above tutorials.

When I use this code:

```
$query = new SolrQuery();

$query->setQuery('lucene');

$query->setStart(0);

$query->setRows(10);

$query->addField('id')->addField('date')->addField('Problem')->addField('Solution');

$query_response = $client->query($query);

$response = $query_response->getResponse();

print_r($response);
```

I get an error because the class SolrQuery is not found.

Comment: You have to install the extension: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/solr.setup.php but it also hasn't been touched since 2016 and probably won't work with current PHP. You're probably better off using a [composer package](https://packagist.org/?query=solr).

Comment: @Sammitch so I would want to replace my solr-php-client with another extension like Solarium?

Comment: Also - a `#` denotes a local anchor in a URL and is never intended for usage directly in a Solr client - it's only relevant inside the browser. It should never be included (i.e. the path would be `/solr/sqltest`) in the path to a Solr client.

Comment: @MatsLindh, thank you, that definitely would have cause issues later on.